# How to make reactive @WebFilter work properly with @RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am trying to make a reactive `@WebFilter` that executes stuff *before* and *after* the actual server exchange (i. e. the controller code handling the request):

```java
public static class Foobar implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Mono.empty()
                .doOnEach(s -> /* BEFORE */))
                .then(chain.filter(exchange) /* CONTROLLER */)
                .and(Mono.empty().doOnEach(s -> /* AFTER */))
                .and(Mono.empty().doFinally(s -> /* FINALLY */));
    }
}
```

Everything works as expected for simple `GET` requests that return a `Mono`:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public static class Foo {

    @GetMapping
    @PostMapping(value = "foo")
    public Mono<String> foo(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return Mono.just("FOOBAR").map(e -> "OK");
    }
}
```

But something really unexpected happens when the controller receives a parameter annotated as `@RequestBody`. Say, for example a `POST` request that takes a `Mono<String>` from the client:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping
public static class Bar {

    @PostMapping(value = "bar")
    public Mono<String> bar(ServerWebExchange exchange, @RequestBody Mono<String> text) {
        return text.map(s -> "OK");
    }
}
```

In this case, all steps in my filter are executed **before the controller gets to complete the request**. This means that the web exchange is committed independently of the filter and therefore I cannot do anything right after the response is sent back to the client.

So I'm wondering:

- Is this some kind of Spring bug?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Or is this simply the expected behavior?

I've created a small Gist containing a test case that reproduces the problem:

- https://gist.github.com/guillermocalvo/740b4fcab471ebc6fe69227fee6d79d5

---

Edit after Brian's comment:

I still think this might be a bug because `Mono.then` doesn't seem to have any effect at all:

```java
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                .doOnSubscribe(s -> logger.info("onSubscribe response committed:" +
                        exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()))
                .then().doOnEach(s -> logger.info("then doOnEach response committed:" +
                        exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()))
                .doFinally(s -> logger.info("doFinally response committed:" +
                        exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()));
        }
```

Additionally, if I put stuff in `doOnEach` is not executed either:

```java
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                    .doOnSubscribe(s -> logger.info("FILTER-BEFORE-CHAIN/commited=" +
                        response.isCommitted()))
                    .doOnEach(s -> logger.info("FILTER-AFTER-CHAIN/commited=" +
                        response.isCommitted()))
                    .doFinally(s -> logger.info("FILTER-FINALLY/commited=" +
                        response.isCommitted()));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a bug in Spring (nor in Reactor in this case), but rather a wrong choice of operators to achieve what you're trying to do.

- `Mono.doOnEach` is executed for each signal (next element, completion, error, cancel); this will be executed several times per request in our case.
- `Mono.and` joins the termination signals - so it waits for both `Mono` to be done and then completes. But both Monos are not executed sequentially, they're subscribed at the same time. `Mono.just` completes right away, independently of what happens with the filter chain.

In your case, you don't need to have something more complex than adding one operator when the processing starts (`doOnSubscribe` happens when the mapping has been done and we're starting to execute the handler) and another one when we're done (`doFinally` happens when it's done, with completion, error or cancellation).

```
    @Component
    public class MyFilter implements WebFilter {

        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

        @Override
        public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
            return chain.filter(exchange)
                .doOnSubscribe(s -> logger.info("onSubscribe response committed:" +
                        exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()))
                .doFinally(s -> logger.info("doFinally response committed:" + 
                        exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()));
        }
    }
```

Note that this approach works as long as you're not performing blocking operations in the `DoOnXYZ` methods, as they're side effects methods. Doing so will create significant performance problems in your application (and reactor might even reject that operation with an exception). So logging, adding an element to a map are fine - but publishing something to an event queue, for example, is not. In this case, you should use instead chain operations with `Mono.then()`.

### Edit

I don't think there is a bug with `Mono.then()` - `doOnEach` only works with signals sent downstream (next, error, complete). In this case, you should only get the complete signal. If you'd like to get the context in all cases, you can take a look at `Mono.deferWithContext`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This approach has the next disadvantages, though:

1. If the `Mono` was subscribed a second time, then wouldn't the *before* callback be executed twice?
2. `doOnSubscribe` and `doFinally` don't allow the callbacks access the reactive context, which was the whole reason for that specific choice of operators.

Comment: 1. you can't subscribe twice to an exchange in WebFlux, so this case should never happen. 2. that wasn't clear from your question. You could use a single doOnEach and react on the signal type.

Comment: 1. It's good to know that WebFlux exchanges cannot be subscribed more than once, that makes things simpler :) Thanks for pointing that out.
2. My bad, I omitted the context part, because I wanted to simplify things as much as possible. Problem with `doOnEach` is that it *never* gets executed. I updated [my gist](https://gist.github.com/guillermocalvo/740b4fcab471ebc6fe69227fee6d79d5) just in case you want to check it out.